# Make cell color match neighboring cell only if text is present

Tags: google-sheets

I am working in a Google Doc spreadsheet and trying to make the background colors of cells in Column C match those of the neighboring cells in Column B as soon as any text is entered.

Column B is a pull down with 5 choices. Two choices have pink backgrounds and the others are white.

I want blank cells in Column C to stay white (even if B is pink) until text is entered, then match the color in B and update if B is updated. Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Emily, it will help people work on your question if you can provide a copy of it, with any sensitive data removed.  Also be sure to turn on Sharing, and allow anyone with the link to edit.  But with conditional formatting, it should be pssoible to do what you want.

Comment: Hello @EmilySing, just like mentioned above, would you mind sharing a sanitized copy of your sheet? Moreover, what have you tried in order to accomplish your task? Cheers!